# How to update one to many relationship using linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have two tables : User and Com. Their association is as such: User has a navigationProperty BaseCom which has multiplicity 0..1, and also a property BaseCom_int_id which is nullable. Com has a navigationProperty Users which has multiplicity *(Many).

Right now User table has a record User1, Com table has two records Com1 and Com2. User1 is now linked to Com1. But I want to update the records such that User1 is no longer linked to Com1 but Com2 instead.

What is the best way that I can do to achieve this using LINQ for SQL?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to retrieve the new Com object and set it as the value for the User. Something like this perhaps?

```
var user = db.Users.Where(x => x.Name == "User1").Single();
var com = db.Coms.Where(x => x.Name == "Com2").Single();

user.BaseCom = com;

db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: I tried out the method. I got an InvalidOperationException which states: Multiplicity constraint violated. The role Com of the relationship 'DBModel.ComUser' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1. Any ideas? Thanks.